# Select2 populate another select2 tags

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 v4,
I have a select2 that make an ajax request and return a nested array like:

```
[{"text":"item1","id":1,"user":[{"text":"item 1.1","id":1},{"text":"item 1.2","id":2}]},
```

with the second array ("user") I want to dinamically populate a select2 tags.

My problem is that when I want to add a tag (ajax request), initial values disappear.

This is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lmnfur4z/

(the only solution that I found is to nest the select2, if u have a more elegant solution is better)

Thanks in advance

G

Comment: I have solved prepopulating the select with:`code`    $.each(data.users, function( index, value ) {

     if($.inArray(value.id,breed_results) == -1){
       $('#razze').append($('<option selected="selected" value="'+value.id+'">'+value.text+'</option>'));
       breed_results.push(value.id);      
     }
    });
    
`code`

Comment: Want to wrap that up in an answer here (with your modified jsfiddle)? I think it would greatly benefit others who have the same question (assuming this wasn't a duplicate).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chaining multiple Select2 together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244576/chaining-multiple-select2-together)