# Chain Select2 via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm looking to achieve 2 things:

1. Allow select options to be searchable and filterable.
2. Auto-select value if the given options are only 1

The below code achieves my 1st point but I'm not sure how, given the current implementation, I can achieve my 2nd point. Selecting a value gets added to `args` so when a select2 is open it queries the database with the updated `args` and returns filtered options **for that specific select2**. The working version looks like this:

```
jQuery( 'document' ).ready( function( $ ) {
            
    let select2s = [];
    let args = {};
    
    
    /**
     * Clear select2 values
     */
    function clear_select2s( except_name ) {
        
        except_name = ( 'undefined' !== typeof except_name ) ? except_name : '';
        
        select2s.forEach( function( $select2, key ) {
            if( $select2.attr( 'name' ) == except_name ) { return; }
            $select2.val( '' );
        } );
        
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Initialize select2s
     */
    $( '#s2Container .select2' ).each( function() {
        
        let name = $( this ).attr( 'name' );
        let placeholder = $( this ).attr( 'placeholder' );
        let $select2 = $( this ).select2( {
            allowClear: true,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            ajax: {
                type: 'post',
                url: test.ajaxurl,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function( params ) {
                    return {
                        action: 'select2_filtering',
                        return: name,
                        args: Object.assign( args, {
                            'search': params.term
                        } ),
                    };
                },
                processResults: function( response ) {
                    return {results: response.data.options};
                },
            },
        } );
        
        /* Push select into Array */
        select2s.push( $select2 );
    } );
    
    
    /**
     * Remove selected value from arguments
     */
    $( '#s2Container .select2' ).on( 'select2:unselecting', function() {
        
        let name = $( this ).attr( 'name' );
        args[ name ] = '';
        
        clear_select2s();
        
    } );
    
    /**
     * Add selected value to arguments
     */
    $( '#s2Container .select2' ).on( 'select2:select', function() {
        
        let name = $( this ).attr( 'name' );
        let value = $( this ).val();
        
        Object.assign( args, {[name]:value} );
        
        clear_select2s( name );
        
    } );
    
} );
```

HTML

```
<div id="s2Container">
    <select class="select2" name="product_id" placeholder="Select Product"></select>
    <select class="select2" name="category_id" placeholder="Select Category"></select>
    <select class="select2" name="brand_id" placeholder="Select Brand"></select>
</div>
```

---

The above code filters the select options via ajax, great. The problem is that my return is only returning options for the current select2.

If I return the data for *all* options for all selects then my understanding is that I need to rebuild each select2 entirely. Destroying and rebuilding the select2 then loses the ajax functionality. Doing all of this while inside the `processResults` seems flawed and I'm not sure the better way to go about it.

---

If I break this into 2 ajax calls, one for the initial load of select2 options and one that processes the `on( 'select2:select' )` then I end up with way more ajax calls than I need, and my `select2:select` ajax gets overwritten with the initial select2 instance ajax.

---

What's the best way to populate multiple select2 options dynamically, based on one-another? How would I then set a selected value if the returned option count is only 1?

Comment: I am familiar with this similar question regarding [chaining select2s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248504/800452) but it's very generic and doesn't really answer any of my questions. It's not as simple as ranges, my selectors are generic and don't have IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Select2 makes it very difficult to switch out active options. I had to ensure the select2 was `.empty()` then I had to destroy the instance and recreate the entire thing with the same settings. It was a pain. In the end, I decided that it's easier to simply not work with the select2 ajax population and populate them after initialization. Here's what I came up with:

```
jQuery( 'document' ).ready( function( $ ) {
            
    let args = {};
    
    
    /**
     * Update all select2s with fresh options
     */
    function update_select2s() {
        
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'post',
            url: test.ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'product_filtering',
                args: args,
            },
            success: function( response ) {
                
                let options = response.data.results;
                
                for( const [ key, values ] of Object.entries( options ) ) {
                    
                    if( ! $( '#s2Container select[name="' + key + '"]' ).length ) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    let $select2    = $( '#s2Container select[name="' + key + '"]' );
                    let selected    = $select2.val();
                    let name        = $select2.attr( 'name' );
                    let placeholder = $select2.attr( 'placeholder' );
                    
                    /**
                     * If we have a select2, empty and destroy it.
                     * This will allow us to reinitialize the select2 with fresh options.
                     * Select2 instance is not yet initialized on first run.
                     */
                    if( $select2.data( 'select2' ) ) {
                        $select2.empty().select2( 'destroy' );
                    }
                    
                    $select2.select2( {
                        allowClear: true,
                        placeholder: placeholder,
                        data: values,
                    } );
                    
                    /**
                     * If there is only one option, select 2 automatically.
                     */
                    if( values.length > 1 ) {
                        $select2.val( '' ).trigger( 'change.select2' );
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
        } );
        
    }
    
    /* Populate Select2 options */
    update_select2s();
    
    
    $( '#s2Container .select2' ).on( 'select2:unselect', function() {

        let name = $( this ).attr( 'name' );
        delete args[ name ];
        
        update_select2s();
        
    } );
    
    
    $( '#s2Container .select2' ).on( 'select2:select', function() {
        
        let name = $( this ).attr( 'name' );
        let value = $( this ).val();
        
        /**
         * If a named arg already exists, this means the user wants change
         * We need to clear our args and give our select2s fresh data.
         */
        if( args.hasOwnProperty( name ) && args[name].length ) {
            args = {[name]:value};
        } else {
            Object.assign( args, {[name]:value} );
        }
        
        update_select2s();
        
    } );
    
} );
```

With this update, I'm also not returning data for a specific select2 but all the select2s. Return data keyed by select names:

```
{
    product_id: [ {id: 1, text: 'foo'}, {id: 1,text: 'foo'} ],
    category_id: [ {id: 1,text: 'xyz'}, {id: 1,text: '123'} ],
}
```